# Looking for method to combine images to make a video through phonegap platform for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ffmpeg, libav

I'm looking to write an application that could combine images and then to form a video. I'm working with Phonegap framework to be available for use on Android and IOS.

My question is what sort of process is involved to achieve this?

At this stage I've tried to read about ffmpeg, most of the questions existing on stackoverflow talk of having to get the source, compiling to make a series of libraries for use. With those libraries it needs to be tied in with the Android/IOS libraries? (I notice there is an 'android.jar' with the project file in eclipse. Would it exist in there?)  Afterwards my confusion lies with how is this implemented into Phonegap. Develop a plugin?

Just to add, libav according to wiki, has hardware accelerated H.264 decoding whilst using x.264 for encoding for Android. How does that work? Is this something accessed from libav libraries and then have to compiled in within the android.jar?

I may have confused terms in trying to describe what I do not know.

Any help would be appreciated.